# Web API Controller is not recognizing newly added methods

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm adding methods to an additional Web API controller. Testing out one of the existing methods I'm able to hit my break points. Yet if I try to call into one of the new ones I get a 404. I'm testing locally using IIS Express and Postman. Examples below, any idea what could cause this?

When I try to call the new endpoint this is the response I receive:

```
    {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:53453/api/nisperson/addnewconnection'.",
"MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'NISPerson' that matches the request."}
```

**Existing method:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("register")]
public ClientResponse PostRegisterPerson(HttpRequestMessage req, PersonModel person)
{
  // This method is getting hit if I call it from Postman
}
```

**endpoint :** `http://localhost:53453/api/test/register`

**Newly Added Method:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("addnewconnection")]
public ClientResponse PostNewConnection(HttpRequestMessage req, string Email, String FirstName, string LastName)
{
  // This is the new method which when called from Postman cannot be found. 
}
```

**Endpoint:** `http://localhost:53453/api/test/addnewconnection`

Comment: You are missing " " around addnewconnection

Comment: Added the quotes, in the actual code they are there. I made a type while adding the question to StackOverflow.

Comment: When declaring routes I normally use a fully qualified route
 [ActionName("ReIndex")]
        [Route("api/autocomplete/reindex")]

Comment: Just to be sure, have you fully recycled IIS Express?  (sometimes it keeps older instances of the app running in memory...)

Comment: That I have not done, let me try it. I didnt think that was necessary when using IIS express.

Comment: The convention is to have one Post method per controller (resource). If you need more than that, you will need to specify a route explicitly.

Comment: That is normally the convention I follow, in this case I need to work with someone elses code. I tried adding the '[Route("api/test/addnewconnection")]' but so far no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined three *required* parameters in your method signature (`Email`, `FirstName` and `LastName`):

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("addnewconnection")]
public ClientResponse PostNewConnection(HttpRequestMessage req, string Email, String FirstName, string LastName)
{
  // This is the new method which when called from Postman cannot be found. 
}
```

The route handler cannot map this URI: `http://localhost:53453/api/test/addnewconnection` to your method because you are not providing those three required parameters.

The correct URI (leaving your method as is) is actually the following one:

```
http://localhost:53453/api/test/addnewconnection?Email=foo&FirstName=bar&LastName=baz
```

Either provide those parameters inside the URI as shown or turn them as not required providing a default value:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("addnewconnection")]
public ClientResponse PostNewConnection(HttpRequestMessage req, string Email = null, String FirstName = null, string LastName = null)
{
  // This is the new method which when called from Postman cannot be found. 
}
```

Providing a default value will allow you to hit your method using your original URI.

Comment: Thanks! I'm so used to passing in Model objects that I didn't realize this was required with simple types.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that it is expecting other parameters (simple string types) to be supplied in querystring which you are not supplying. So, it is trying to call Post with single parameter and failing to find it. Simple types are by default read from URI. If you want them to read from form body, use FromBody attribute.